# Mostrar valores en un combo Select en la vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

mi problema es que no puedo mostrar el valor del genero del usuario que ya tiene un valor asignado, esto quiero mostrarlo en el combo select de la vista del perfil, el combo select solo me muestra los valores por defecto pero no el valor ya asignado al usuario.

La tabla Gender (genero) tiene los valores 1: Femenino, 2: Masculino, 3: Otro

El usuario tiene asignado el valor 2 (masculino), y la palabra "masculino" es lo que quiero mostrar en el menú select como ya seleccionado al momento de editar perfil

Esta es la vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La opción por defecto del select debería ser Masculino que es lo que tiene asignado el usuario.

Gracias!

Comment: Como te muestra el Genero como texto normal y corriente cierto?, podrias aplicar jquery para poder afectar el select.A y podrias dejar codigo en vez de foto , ya que es más fácil ayudarte.Saludos!

Comment: Simplemente quiero que el select me muestre el genero que tiene el usuario al momento de editar su perfil. Si el usuario es mujer entonces que el primer valor del select sea Femenino, si es hombre, entonces primera valor Masculino, eso es todo

Comment: yo usario un if dentro de el foreach y preguntaria si es igual al genero y pondria el option en selected , si quieres te dejo algo como podiras hacerlo.

Comment: Vale gracias, eso me ayudaría un montón, espero tu código!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira se me ocurre algo como esto para tu código, la lógica sería algo como esto.

```
<div class="form">
    <p>{{__('Genero')}}</p>
<select name="gender" id="gender" class="custom-select selector">
    @foreach($genders as $gender)
            @if(Auth:user()->id_genero == 'algo de valor aca')
        <option value="{{$gender->id}}" selected>{{$gender->name}}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{$gender->id}}" selected>{{$gender->name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

Con esto hago que cuando se cumpla la condición en el if este quede seleccionado.

Comment: se me ocurre algo así , suponiendo que el usuario este logueado

Comment: Exactamente así es, tengo un problema en los ids pero funciona bien, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda.